# Drawing a spiral in a spiral using Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

What is wrong with my code for turtle angie? I want her to spiral inside brad's square circle.

My Code:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(some_turtle):

    for i in range (1,5):
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(90)

def draw_art():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("black")
    #Turtle Brad
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(6)
    brad.pensize(2)
    for i in range(1,37):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)
    #Turtle Angie
    angie = turtle.Screen()
    angie.shape("turtle")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.speed(5)
    angie.pensize(2)
    size=1
    while (True):
        angie.forward(size)
        angie.right(91)
        size = size + 1

    window.exitonclick()

draw_art()
```

Here are photos of I what I want it to look like. I want the outer part of the brad showing and then the circle inside to include the spiral. It should look like the spiral image attached. Thanks!

[image: brad]
[image: angie]

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the `angie = turtle.Turtle()` (not `turtle.Screen()`), another problem you're likely to notice is that your `windowexitonclick()` statement will have no effect.  That is clicking on the window won't exit and close the window because it comes after an infinite `while True:` loop:

```
while (True):
        angie.forward(size)
        angie.right(91)
        size = size + 1

window.exitonclick()
```

and so is never reached.  The simplest way to fix this is, without adding the complexity of timers, is to make this a `for` loop with a range as you use elsewhere so that `angie` eventually stops and lets the next line of code execute.

Finally, it doesn't quite look like your target as `brad` is drawing five sides to his square instead of four.  Once we fix that, it looks correct and `angie` starts from the middle instead of the edge.

A rework of your code with the above and other style changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_square(some_turtle):

    for _ in range(4):
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(90)

def draw_art():

    # Turtle Brad
    brad = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.pensize(2)
    brad.speed("normal")  # 6/normal is the default so don't need to do it

    for _ in range(36):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)

    # Turtle Angie
    angie = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.pensize(2)
    angie.speed(5)  # slightly slower than brad

    size = 1

    for _ in range(300):
        angie.forward(size)
        angie.right(91)
        size += 1

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor("black")

draw_art()

window.exitonclick()
```

Once `angie` finishes her design, you should be able to just click on the window to make it go away.  For a complex design like this, I'd be tempted to set the `turtle.speed()` to "fast" and "fastest" as I've no patience.  (Instead of the numbers use the words 'fastest', 'fast', 'normal', 'slow' & 'slowest' instead to avoid surprises unless you need very fine control over the speed.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You explained that very well. This is really helpful. :) How would you make the turtle shape disappear after the drawing is complete?

Comment: @digi_life, you can use `brad.hideturtle()` (and similarly for angie) to make the turtle itself disappear after it's finished drawing.  (Some programs do this before the turtle draws to avoid showing the turtle at work.)

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
angie = turtle.Screen()
```

It should be:

```
angie = turtle.Turtle()
```

Comment: Incorrect. You actually need both when running from a file.

`turtle.Turtle()` creates the new turtle object, while `turtle.Screen()` opens the screen that the turtle object draws on.

Comment: If you are using an online IDE, you don't need the screen, just the init.

Comment: @Foster The Op is using IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

`angie` is a `Turtle` not a `Screen`.

Change line 22 to 
`angie = turtle.Turtle()`

Answer (score 0):

something simpler would be like this:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
def kuadrado(lado): 
  for i in range(36): #draw the circle of squares
   t.forward(lado)
   t.right(90)
   t.forward(lado)
   t.right(90)
   t.forward(lado)
   t.right(90)
   t.forward(lado)
   t.right(100)
  for i in range(100): #draw the spiral inside the circle of squares
   t.forward(i)
   t.right(80)   

kuadrado(50)

input("<enter>")
```

you only have to adjust the measures of the spiral to have the harmony

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlxYf.png)

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_square(some_turtle):

```
for _ in range(4):
    some_turtle.forward(290)
    some_turtle.right(90)
```

def draw_art():

```
# Turtle Brad
brad = Turtle(shape="turtle")
brad.color("cyan")
brad.pensize(2)
brad.speed("fast")  # 6/normal is the default so don't need to do it

for _ in range(36):
    draw_square(brad)
    brad.right(10)

# Turtle Angie
angie = Turtle(shape="turtle")
angie.color("darkcyan")
angie.pensize(2)
angie.speed(0)  # slightly slower than brad

size = 1

for _ in range(250):
    angie.forward(size)
    angie.right(91)
    size += 0
```

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor("black")

draw_art()

window.exitonclick()

Answer (score -2):

```
#made by jonny big smokes©™®❤ this code  is illegal to use without permission of the king of gypos jonny big smokes
import turtle
import random
colorlistsize = 3
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
tess = turtle.Turtle()

def random_color():
    levels = range(32,256,32)
    return list(random.choice(levels) for _ in range(3))


def color_selector():
  listo = []
  for i in range(colorlistsize):
    listo.append(random_color())
  return listo


while True:
  tess.speed(-1000)
  sz = 2 
  ang = random.randint(58, 302)
  color_list = color_selector()
  for i in range(500):
    tess.right(ang)
    tess.forward(sz)
    color = color_list [i % 3]
    tess.color(color)

    sz = sz+1
  tess.clear()
  tess.reset()
```

Comment: can you edit and add a short explanation about how your code solves the problem?

Comment: This code doesn't run under current Python 3 and turtle.py as it's assuming  the wrong default color mode.  Add `turtle.colormode(255)` near the top to get it to run so you can see it has no bearing on the OP's question.

Comment: Your copyright notice at the top does nothing. You [agreed](http://stackexchange.com/legal) that everything you post here is the property of Stack Exchange.